# How to hide hamburger menu on desktop with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm practicing with jQuery. I wanted to created a simple navbar, like the Bootstrap navbar for example.
I want an hamburger menu on mobile and a "normal" menu on desktop, but I'm blocked.

I don't know how to set a normal menu with inline list items at the right of the h1. I tried to put something like this: `if ($(window).width <= 860) {` on jQuery but it doesn't work.

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/l_wel/kzLs5jou/

EDIT: I solved the problem thanks to your advice to use CSS media queries.

```js
$(function () {
  $('ul').hide();
  $('span#toggleMenu').on('click', function (e) {
    $('ul').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
}

h1 {
  float: left;
}

span {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="container">
    <h1>Toggle Navbar</h1>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <span id="toggleMenu"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-48.png" alt="menu"></span>
      <ul>
        <li class="item">Item1</li>
        <li class="item">Item2</li>
        <li class="item">Item3</li>
        <li class="item">Item4</li>
        <li class="item">Item5</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Use CSS Media Queries, not JQuery. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Do you need change size when change device?

Comment: @ScottMarcus it's the first thing I tried but it didn't work

Comment: @Fr33d0m yes, screen size or device

Comment: So do CSS Media Queries, like says @ScottMarcus

Comment: @Lewis You weren't using them correctly then. Media Queries are the best solution for a problem like this.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, I solved my problem. I was overthinking it with jQuery, the solution was a CSS media query. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You were close with `if ($(window).width <= 860)`.  Note that `width` is a method, not a property, so it needs parentheses:

```
if($(window).width() <= 860) {
  $('span#toggleMenu').hide();
}
```

A better way to accomplish this would be with **[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**:

```
<style>
  @media (max-width: 860px) {
    span#toggleMenu {
      display: none;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
if(window.innerWidth <= 860) {

}
```

Comment: Ow, sorry. Assumed it was jQuery since you mentioned it in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle `nav` change with css using media queries, and then you just need to toggle `ul` on button click.

```js
$('span#toggleMenu').on('click', function(e) {
  $('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75%;
}
#toggleMenu {
  display: none;
}
span {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
   #toggleMenu {
     display: block;
   }
   ul {
     display: none;
   }
   nav {
     position: relative;
   }
   ul {
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 100%;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
   }
}
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  ul {
    display: flex !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="container">
  <h1>Toggle Navbar</h1>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <span id="toggleMenu"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-48.png" alt="menu"></span>
    <ul>
      <li class="item">Item1</li>
      <li class="item">Item2</li>
      <li class="item">Item3</li>
      <li class="item">Item4</li>
      <li class="item">Item5</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```